# Injections from a set of functions to R

Tags: functions, proof-writing

Show there is an injection from $\Bbb  R^2 \to \Bbb R  $

Does there exist an injection from $X \to \Bbb R$ where $X $ is the set of all functions where f(x)=x for all but finitely many x.

This is a past exam question I am stuck on whilst revising. Now I can't even think of an injection for the first part, the only idea I have is the well known injection in the unit square of interlocking the decimals but cannot think of how to extend this to $\Bbb R^2 $ Also my guess is once you find the injection the last part is true as it will be countable due to the finitely many x. This isn't the first countability question I've been stuck on so some sort of model answer would be very helpful to see the style a proof should have in an exam.

Comment: For the first part, you could just do the same interlocking of the decimals as for the unit square? This works as $]-0,1[$ and $\Bbb{R}$ are isomorphic.

For the second one, $X$ is in bijective correspondence to subsets of $\Bbb R$ with finite cardinality. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so we want to show that there is an injection $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ We know that $\#(\mathbb{R}^2)= \#(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}) = c.c = c$ Here I am using cardinal multiplication, you can se a clear proof in Kaplansky, Set theory and Metric Spaces. Ok so we know that $\#(\mathbb{R})=\#(\mathbb{R}^2)$ Therefore there is a bijection between them, in particular an injection.

Comment: I don't even know what cardinal multiplication is, this is from a basic course where the only results we have is the definition of countability and things like a countable union of countable sets is countable